# CommandLineRunner doesn't log into file

Tags: java, spring, log4j, log4j2

I'm strugling to get logger write into file in my CommandLineRunner. Logs get written before SpringApplication.run, but after that they go only into console.

```
@SpringBootApplication
@Log4j2
public class B4bApplication {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    log.info("start");
    SpringApplication.run(B4bApplication.class, args);
    log.info("end"); // this comes only in console
  }
}

@Component
@Log4j2
public class B4bProcess implements CommandLineRunner {
  @Override
  public void run(String... args) throws Exception {
    log.info("Start B4B"); // This comes only in console
  }
}
```

---

From debug logs I see that logfiles are shut down:

```
DEBUG StatusLogger Started configuration XmlConfiguration[...springframework/boot/logging/log4j2/log4j2.xml] OK.
TRACE StatusLogger Stopping XmlConfiguration[location=C:\git\b4b\src\resources\log4j2.xml]...
TRACE StatusLogger XmlConfiguration notified 3 ReliabilityStrategies that config will be stopped.
```

My config file looks like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Configuration>
  <Properties>
    <Property name="logDir">logs</Property>
    <Property name="loggingPattern">%d{HH:mm:ss} %-5p %c{1} - %m%n</Property>
  </Properties>
  <Appenders>
    <Console name="STDOUT">
      <PatternLayout pattern="${loggingPattern}"/>
    </Console>
    <File name="general" fileName="${logDir}/general_${sys:COUNTRY_CODE}_${date:yyyyMMdd}.log">
      <PatternLayout pattern="${loggingPattern}"/>
    </File>
  </Appenders>
  <Loggers>
    <Logger name="com.swedbank" level="${env:INSURANCE_LOG_LEVEL:-info}" additivity="true">
      <AppenderRef ref="general" level="info"/>
      <AppenderRef ref="STDOUT" level="info"/>
    </Logger>
    <Root level="DEBUG">
      <AppenderRef ref="general"/>
    </Root>
  </Loggers>

</Configuration>
```

Comment: This happened when I provided log4jxml file location as environment variable. When I deleted it and let system find the file from classpath, then file entries started to appear.